# jQuery Mobile pages with different background images

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on hybrid mobile application using Cordova + jQuery Mobile on Android . I have two html pages which are to have different images as background. I use following code to set page background:

```
 .ui-mobile .ui-page {
     background : transparent;
 }
 body.ui-mobile-viewport {
     background : url(img/homescreen.png) no-repeat center center;
 }
```

The problem in this case that second page has the first's background and exact same same code does not overwrite its background.

In second case I tried to use specific ID to assign background:

```
#firstpage{
    background: transparent url(img/first.png) no-repeat center center;
}
#secondpage{
    background: transparent url(img/second.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

The problem in second case that only the first page has background and the second one has blank white color. The pages themselves have following structure:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="firstpage">
        <div class="ui-content" role="main">
            <div class="ui-grid-a"> <!-- two column grid -->
                <div class="ui-block-a">  
                     <a href="secondpage.html"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The second one pretty much the same. Any suggestions how to address this issue?

**EDIT:**
Everything works fine on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5o75shsw/
Probably because both pages in the same html document.

Comment: Are you sure `second.png` exists, and that it's file extension is correct?

Comment: Phrases like "pretty much the same" make me nervous, especially when working with things that are so dependent on context. Post a jsbin or fiddle with the repro case so we can take a look.

Comment: Added JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5o75shsw/ , and everything works just fine there, two separate html documents might be the reason, not sure though. I will check it

Comment: It works when I combined both pages into one html, I am wondering is there a way to do the same for multiple html case...